# What is the correct way to implement multiple views on top of each other?

Tags: android

A bit of context: I am trying to implement a SearchView, when onQueryTextChange is called, it displays a ProgressBar, and when the query is done it hides the progress bar and displays another view depending on the outcome of the query. If the query returns nothing, it makes a textview visible saying "No Results" and if there is data, it populates the recyclerView.

My question is, what is the correct way of implementing this? 
Do I stack them all on top of each other and make each one visible/invisible depending on the outcome of the query? Or do I use a viewflipper to display a fragment for no result and a fragment containing a recyclerview? Or lastly there is another way I do not know of?

This is what my search fragment looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="@color/colorWhite">

<android.support.v7.widget.SearchView
    android:id="@+id/fragsearch_searchView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:queryBackground="@android:color/transparent"
    app:queryHint="Search"
    app:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:background="@color/backgroundColor"/>

<View
    android:id="@+id/fragsearch_divider1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="1dp"
    android:background="@color/dividerColor"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragsearch_searchView"/>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/fragsearch_recycler"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragsearch_divider1"/>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/fragsearch_progress_layout"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_below="@+id/fragsearch_divider1"
    android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/fragsearch_progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/fragsearch_textview_noresults"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/fragsearch_divider1"
    android:padding="12dp"
    android:text="No Results Found"
    android:visibility="invisible"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Right now I'm just stacking all of them on top of each other and changing the visibility on each one. Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Try using searchview inside toolbar if it is possible as it will consume less screen space!

Comment: Will do, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use a ViewFlipper for this. This way you can encapsulate the various view states in separate layouts and verify at design time that the correct layout is displayed. Much nicer than setting visibility on different Views.

```
<ViewFlipper>

    <ViewGroup1>
    </ViewGroup1>

    <ViewGroup2>
    </ViewGroup2>

</ViewFlipper>
```

To switch between the different children of a ViewFlipper call `setDisplayedChild(index)`,

Answer (score 1):

FrameLayout is used for this purpose.It is very useful for arranging views on top of each other.In your case replace RelativeLayout with FrameLayout.

Answer (score 0):

I have done it using `Constraintlayout` considering searchview inside toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="@dimen/padding_8dp">

    <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:id="@+id/recycler_company_details"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_empty_data"
            android:text="No data available!!"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:visibility="gone"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:textColor="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using framelayout for this purpose, also we can easily set children layout gravity, it gets rendered perfectly. Relativelayout could also help, but we should avoid views termed as  'Legacy'.